# Python read dict values from lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

In python I have:

```
my_dict = dict({'98:1E:19:7E:8F:30': ['SAGEMCOM BROADBAND SAS', '22'], '98:1E:19:7E:8F:32': ['SAGEMCOM BROADBAND SAS1']})
```

and would like to generate a list of all values, so I tried:

```
[[sub_val for sub_val in val] for val in my_dict.values()]
```

But this gives me:

```
[['SAGEMCOM BROADBAND SAS', '22'], ['SAGEMCOM BROADBAND SAS1']]
```

while I wanted:

```
['SAGEMCOM BROADBAND SAS', '22', 'SAGEMCOM BROADBAND SAS1']
```

What's wrong with what I've done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an additional `for` clause in the list comprehension to iterate through the sub-lists:

```
[value for values in my_dict.values() for value in values]
```

Comment: You are assuming each list has one item only...

Comment: In that case it's a question of flattening a nested list that has been answered for thousands of times and can be found with a search easily.